# Why isn't my dart/polymer custom element rendering?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to write a custom element in dart/polymer but nothing renders and no errors are displayed.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  All the details are in the following gist.

https://gist.github.com/heuristicat/7947755

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Great first question, complete with a gist.

Comment: Thank you.  Hopefully there will be a great answer too.  =)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  The following line...

```html
<link rel="import" src="hello-world.html">
```

should have been...

```html
<link rel="import" href="hello-world.html">
```

It is so obvious but all the src attributes in the script tags played tricks on my mind.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Polymer you need the following script tags within the `<head>` tag after any element imports

```html
<script type='application/dart'>
  export 'package:polymer/init.dart';
      </script>

<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change anything.  Same behavior... no rendered element.